# EverNote API compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, api, evernote

I am trying to build the EverNote API on ubuntu. I downloaded the Thrift library and linked the API files to the library. When I try to compile the API I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
NoteStore.o: In function `evernote::edam::NoteStoreProcessor::process_fn(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int)':
NoteStore.cpp:(.text+0xc9ad): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To compile the library, Just link to the Thrift header files you can get here: http://thrift.apache.org/download/. Then once that is installed, compile it AS A LIBRARY. That was my mistake for anyone who might be having the same problem in the future.